# Have I used Singleton with Realm Database correct?

Tags: java, android, design-patterns, singleton, realm

I have an app where the user can create/delete/edit to a list from a DialogFragment. Before I had a method like this in my DialogFragments: `MainActivtity.adapter.add(String name, String location, double price);`

`adapter` is my adapter object for the recyclerView. The class for the adapter had my create/delete/edit methods for the items in the recyclerView. Which was called like shown above which also is a horrible way to call mehtods as I understand.

So I choose to put all these CRUD methods in a one singleton class and call these method like this: `Service.getInstance().add(...);`

Is this a correct approach and what could I have done better?

This is how I made the singleton class that now contains my CRUD methods, instead of putting them in my adapter class for the recyclerView as before.

```
public class Service {

private static Realm realm;
private static Service service = new Service();

private Service() {
    realm = Realm.getInstance(App.getAppContex());
}

public static Service getInstance(){

    if(service == null){
        service = new Service();
    }
    return service;
}



   public void add(String name, String location, double price) {


    ShopListItem shopListItem = new ShopListItem();

    shopListItem.setName(name);
    shopListItem.setLocation(location);
    shopListItem.setPrice(price);
    shopListItem.setTimestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
    shopListItem.setIsBought(0);

    realm.beginTransaction();
    realm.copyToRealm(shopListItem);
    realm.commitTransaction();
}


public void removeItem(int position, List<ShopListItem> shopListItems) {

    realm.beginTransaction();
    shopListItems.remove(position);
    realm.commitTransaction();
}
```

**This class is just used for getting the global/Application context**

```
public class App extends Application {


public static Application sApplication;

public static Application getsApplication(){
    return sApplication;
}

public static Context getAppContex(){

    return getsApplication();
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    sApplication = this;
}
}
```

***Question updated from here:***

**Here is the new approach based on suggestions from comments:**
Now everytime I want to make a CRUD operation in the Realm Database, I always start with the getDefaultInstance for my realm object and finish of with realm.close(); this procces is reapted in every CRUD method.

```
public class Service {

private Realm realm;
private static Service service = new Service();

private Service() {


}

public static Service getInstance(){

    if(service == null){
        service = new Service();
    }
    return service;
}

public void removeItem(int position, List<ShopListItem> shopListItems) {
    //new: realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    realm.beginTransaction();
    shopListItems.remove(position);
    realm.commitTransaction();
    realm.close();
    //new: realm.close();
}
```

**Realm configurations is now moved to my Application class as suggested by Realm.**

```
public class App extends Application {


public static Application sApplication;

public static Application getsApplication(){
    return sApplication;
}

public static Context getAppContex(){

    return getsApplication();
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    sApplication = this;
final RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration = new    RealmConfiguration.Builder(App.getAppContex()).build();
    realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfiguration);
}
}
```

Comment: Where do you close the realm instance?

Comment: A singleton pattern is generally dangerous, especially if you access the singleton from different threads. See these two sections in the docs for more information about how to handle the Realm life cycle: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#controlling-the-lifecycle-of-realm-instances and https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#closing-realm-instances

Comment: @TimCastelijns in my onDestroy methods.

Comment: @ChristianMelchior Allright thanks for the links, I will check them out

Comment: @ChristianMelchior Should I call close(); after everytime I call methods like add/edit/delete in Realm?

Comment: Not necessarily, but if you want to make all the methods thread safe, you should open the Realm at the beginning of the method and close it again when exiting. Just note that Realm data is only accessible while the instance is open, so this will only work if you don't return any data.

Comment: @ChristianMelchior I just updated my question, please take a look at my new approach. we are from the same city btw  (:

Comment: There is now no reason to have the `Realm' as a data member, and it should never have been a static member in the first place. Make it a local variable and you are thread-safe.

Comment: @EJP Do you mean that it has to be a local variable in the remove method and not a class member?

Comment: I not only meant it, I said it.

Comment: @EJP I have done all the changes now. Look at the updated question.  I think everything now looks good and is best practice.

Comment: Eh? Best practice? Not on your nelly. You still havent made it a local variable, so it still isn't thread-safe.

Answer (score 2):

You should not be using realm with singleton at all. As realm is thread oriented. you should open new default instance and close it.

Or you can use a map of threadId vs realm object. where thread is weak reference.

Comment: The reason I have made the Service class a singleton, is so I can call my CRUD method from anywhere in my app/code, So I dont have to forexample to make a add(); method for every class that need this method

Comment: @Muddz so make a static class with add/remove in it?

Comment: Best way to make singleton in java is no more by design pattern.You can use dagger 2 to create singleton .which is much reusable, testable and modifiable

Answer (score 1):

`Realm` represents a thread-confined local instance that needs to be closed when the thread reaches end of execution (or the local instance is no longer needed).

Any objects retrieved from the Realm are bound to the Realm's lifecycle, meaning they are invalidated once every Realm instance is closed on the given thread (the call to `getInstance()` increases a reference count, and `close()` decreases it).

So creating a `static Realm realm` will most likely be accessible only on the UI thread.

To use Realm as a singleton (and be able to create/retrieve thread-local Realm instance in a reliable manner), you'd need something like [this](https://github.com/Zhuinden/singleton-realm-manager/blob/636db14b1f98733c78b1c6c70ae3502067037d0b/realm-manager/src/main/java/com/zhuinden/realmmanager/RealmManager.java):

```
@Singleton
public class RealmManager {
    private final ThreadLocal<Realm> localRealms = new ThreadLocal<>();

    @Inject
    RealmManager() {
    }

    /**
     * Opens a reference-counted local Realm instance.
     *
     * @return the open Realm instance
     */
    public Realm openLocalInstance() {
        checkDefaultConfiguration();
        Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        if(localRealms.get() == null) {
            localRealms.set(realm);
        }
        return realm;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the local Realm instance without adding to the reference count.
     *
     * @return the local Realm instance
     * @throws IllegalStateException when no Realm is open
     */
    public Realm getLocalInstance() {
        Realm realm = localRealms.get();
        if(realm == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "No open Realms were found on this thread.");
        }
        return realm;
    }

    /**
     * Closes local Realm instance, decrementing the reference count.
     *
     * @throws IllegalStateException if there is no open Realm.
     */
    public void closeLocalInstance() {
        checkDefaultConfiguration();
        Realm realm = localRealms.get();
        if(realm == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "Cannot close a Realm that is not open.");
        }
        realm.close();
        // noinspection ConstantConditions
        if(Realm.getLocalInstanceCount(Realm.getDefaultConfiguration()) <= 0) {
            localRealms.set(null);
        }
    }

    private void checkDefaultConfiguration() {
        if(Realm.getDefaultConfiguration() == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("No default configuration is set.");
        }
    }
}
```

That way, you can open/close Realm at the beginning/end of execution, but still obtain Realm without necessarily passing it as a method argument.

```
private void doSomething() {
    Realm realm = realmManager.getLocalInstance();
```

Or

```
    realmManager.openLocalInstance();
    // .. do whatever
    realmManager.closeLocalInstance();
```