# Have I implemented EpicPandaForce's RealmManager correctly?

Tags: java, android, realm

I am new to Realm (and Android development) and I would like to use a Singleton class to simplify Realm data management so it's easier for my friends to use in our group project.

EpicPandaForce have written a singleton class called RealmManager [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46394426/8507341), but I couldn't find an example in implementing it, so this is what I have tried:

```
public class RealmManager {
    private static RealmManager instance;
    private final ThreadLocal<Realm> localRealm = new ThreadLocal<>();

    RealmManager(){}

    public synchronized static RealmManager getInstance(){
        if(instance == null){
            instance = new RealmManager();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public Realm openLocalInstance() {
        Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        if(localRealm.get() == null) {
            localRealm.set(realm);
        }
        return realm;
    }

    public Realm getLocalInstance() {
        Realm realm = localRealm.get();
        if(realm == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("No open Realms were found on this thread.");
        }
        return realm;
    }

    public void closeLocalInstance() {
        Realm realm = localRealm.get();
        if(realm == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                "Cannot close a Realm that is not open.");
        }
        realm.close();
        if(Realm.getLocalInstanceCount(Realm.getDefaultConfiguration()) <= 0) {
        localRealm.set(null);
        }
    }

    public void storePreferenceDao(int userID, String rank){
        final PreferenceDao preferenceDao = new PreferenceDao();
        preferenceDao.setUserID(userID);
        preferenceDao.setRank(rank);
        openLocalInstance();
        getLocalInstance().executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm realm) {
                realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(preferenceDao);
            }
        }, new Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess(){
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(){
                System.out.println("Data is stored successfully!");
            }
        }, new Realm.Transaction.OnError(){
            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable error){
                System.out.println("There is an error in storePreferenceDao()");
            }
        });
        closeLocalInstance();
    }
```

So when my friends want to store some data, they can just use:

```
RealmManager.getInstance().storePreferenceDao(123, "Alpaca");
```

Is this how it is supposed to be used or is it redundant? How can I make it more efficient?

Comment: Make `getInstance()` of your `RealmManager`
 class as `synchronized` for Thread safe.

Comment: @vinS no I am looking to implement EpicPandaForce's RealmManager class into my app, but I don't find any examples anywhere.

Comment: @Chithra Noted! Thanks. I will edit it now.

Comment: I re-opened this because this is not a duplicate...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually in this case, that method can still be called only from UI thread, and the local instance should be closed in the transaction callback (otherwise the onSuccess/onError won't be called)

You could make a method that is able to execute on bg thread if able, and on current thread if already on a bg thread

```
// method in RealmManager
public final void runTransaction(Realm.Transaction transaction) {
    runTransaction(transaction, null, null);
}

public final void runTransaction(Realm.Transaction transaction, Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess onSuccess) {
    runTransaction(transaction, onSuccess, null);
}

public final void runTransaction(Realm.Transaction transaction, Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess onSuccess, Realm.Transaction.OnError onError) {
    Realm realm = openLocalInstance();
    if(realm.isAutoRefresh()) {
        realm.executeTransactionAsync(transaction, new Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                try {
                    if(onSuccess != null) {
                        onSuccess.onSuccess();
                    }
                } finally {
                    closeLocalInstance();
                }
            }
        }, new Realm.Transaction.OnError() {
            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                try {
                    if(onError != null) {
                        onError.onError(e);
                    }
                } finally {
                    closeLocalInstance();
                }
            }
        });
    } else {
        try {
            realm.executeTransaction(transaction);
            if(onSuccess != null) {
                onSuccess.onSuccess();
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            if(onError != null) {
                onError.onError(e);
            }
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } finally {
            closeLocalInstance();
        }
    }
}
```

If you add this method, then you can now execute a transaction that will either be executed on background thread via `async` transaction method if possible, using `synchronous` transaction method if not on a looper thread (f.ex. background thread)

This way you can now do

```
public void storePreferenceDao(int userID, String rank) {
    final PreferenceDao preferenceDao = new PreferenceDao();
    preferenceDao.setUserID(userID);
    preferenceDao.setRank(rank);
    runTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm realm) {
            realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(preferenceDao);
        }
    }, new Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess(){
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(){
            System.out.println("Data is stored successfully!");
        }
    }, new Realm.Transaction.OnError(){
        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable error){
            System.out.println("There is an error in storePreferenceDao()");
        }
    });
}
```

Or just

```
public void storePreferenceDao(int userID, String rank) {
    final PreferenceDao preferenceDao = new PreferenceDao();
    preferenceDao.setUserID(userID);
    preferenceDao.setRank(rank);
    runInTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm realm) {
            realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(preferenceDao);
        }
    });
}
```

You know, I always felt I should add a `runTransaction()` method to that example. Whether it should default to using `executeTransactionAsync` by default if able or not is up for debate, though.

Comment: Thank you so much! Just one question, would storePreferenceDao(int, String) still be in RealmManager class?

Comment: You can, or you can make it into its own class that is created by the RealmManager (and gives itself over as a constructor parameter), similarly to how Room does it. Or you can make it singleton and give it RealmManager as a constructor parameter, which is what I'd do with DI

Comment: Thank you! I am going to code everything in RealmManager for now.

Comment: Also you used `runInTransaction()` in `storePreferenceDao()` instead of `runTransaction()` you gave me.

Comment: that is a typo.

Comment: I've started implementing something on top of android architecture components [here](https://github.com/Zhuinden/realm-monarchy) you can check progress there

Comment: how to get realm object for query on background thread? getLocalInstance throws exception as we are not on same thread. I am using new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
           // how to get realm object here
                    }
                });

            }
        }).start();

Comment: `try { Realm realm = open() } finally { close() }` and then you can use `getLocalInstance()` in methods inbetween

Comment: one more question. As open return realm object, so why we are not using that object? and use object from getLocalInstance() method

Comment: It's up to you, you can use it, and you can also get it with get() afterwards

Comment: thanks. I have implemented "runTransaction" for asyn calls but app crash on finally block "closeLocalInstance" because no relam instance are open on that time. Why it happens? any idea

Comment: That depends on where you're closing it ;)

Comment: I am calling close() on finally block. Crash occurs on runTransaction method.

Comment: Then you are also closing it somewhere else unexpectedly.

Answer (score 0):

A simple Singleton example,

```
public class MySingleton {
private static MySingleton sMySingleton;

//private constructor.
private MySingleton() {
    if (sMySingleton != null){
        throw new RuntimeException("Use getInstance() for the instance");
    }
} 

public synchronized static MySingleton getInstance() {
    if (sMySingleton == null){ 
        sMySingleton = new MySingleton();
    }
    return sMySingleton;
}
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

This can be not the best answer but here how i am using realm in my applications

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public Realm realm;
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_base);
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    }

}
```

Extend BaseActivity in other Activities according to your use

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

       @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //Here you can directly access realm object and perform your task
        realm.where()//just example
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if(realm!=null)
           realm.close();
       //Don't forget to close realm object
    }

}
```

I am not saying this is the best way but it one the best way. using this way i can easily manage my realm class and can reduce errors related to realm.For fragments You can make BaseFragment and extend it in other fragments.

Hope this will help you...Let me know if you get any other better way for this