# Realm with Singleton Pattern in Android: Pros and Cons

Tags: android, singleton, realm, realm-mobile-platform

Hi I have gone through the best practices in Realm and according to it the best way to handle Realm instances is to open a realm instance in `onCreate()` method of an Activity using `relam = Realm.getDefaultInstance()` and close it in `onDestroy()` using `realm.close()`.

But currently I have following singleton structure in my code. I need to know the pros and cons of the following singleton structure over the best practice suggested in realm docs.

**Here is my code: Approach 1**

```
public class RealmManager {
private static final String TAG = "RealmManager";

private RealmAsyncTask transactionManager;
private static RealmManager mInstance = null;

public static RealmManager getInstance() {
    if (mInstance == null)
        mInstance = new RealmManager();
    return mInstance;
}

private Realm mRealm;

protected RealmManager() {
    mRealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
}

public void saveOrUpdateChatChannel(ChatChannel channel) {
    mRealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    mRealm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(@NonNull Realm bgRealm) {
            bgRealm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(channel);
        }
    }, new Realm.Transaction.OnError() {
        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable error) {
            Log.e(TAG,"Failed to update Channel");
        }
    });
}

public void deleteChatChannel(String channelID, OnRealmDatabaseListener mRealmListener) {
    mRealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

    mRealm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(@NonNull Realm realm) {
            RealmResults<ChatChannel> result = realm.where(ChatChannel.class).equalTo("channelId", channelID).findAll();
            result.deleteAllFromRealm();
        }
    }, new Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            if (mRealmListener != null)
                mRealmListener.isDatabaseOperationSuccess(channelID, true);
        }
    }, new Realm.Transaction.OnError() {
        @Override
        public void onError(@NonNull Throwable error) {

        }
    });
}

public void closeRealm() {
    if (mRealm != null) {
        mRealm.close();
    }
    if (transactionManager != null) {
        transactionManager.cancel();
    }
  }

}
```

So in the Approach 1, I will be creating realm instances in my activities, services, intent services using `RealmManager.getInstance()` and then continue to do transactions. And in all my Activity `onDestroy()` methods i am closing the realm using `RealmManager.closeRealm()`. So my question is, if the `RealmManager.closeRealm()` which is called in Activity `onDestroy()`, will affect any transactions which are executing in Service?

**Here is my code: Approach 2**

```
public class RealmManager {

private static RealmManager mInstance = null;

public static RealmManager getInstance() {
    if (mInstance == null)
        mInstance = new RealmManager();
    return mInstance;
}

private Realm mRealm;

protected RealmManager(){
    mRealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
}

public void addClockModel(ClockRLM clockRLM,OnRealmDatabaseListener mRealmListener){

    RealmAsyncTask transactionManager = mRealm.executeTransactionAsync(realm -> realm.copyToRealm(clockRLM), new Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            Log.d("Clocke ", "Inserted TimeStamp " + clockRLM.getTimeStamp());
            if (mRealmListener != null)
                mRealmListener.isDatabaseOperationSuccess(clockRLM,true);
            if (transactionManager != null)
                transactionManager.cancel();
        }
    }, new Realm.Transaction.OnError() {
        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable error) {
            if (transactionManager != null)
                transactionManager.cancel();
        }
    });
  }
}
```

So in the Approach 2, I will be creating realm instances in my activities, services, intent services using `RealmManager.getInstance()` and then continue to do transactions. I am not sure where to close realm if i use Approach 2. What if i do not close it anywhere and only when the app closes, the RealmManager gets destroyed and realm instance will be destroyed. OR i need to close the realm instance in the application level (I am not sure whether we can close instance in the application level).

Which one is better among Approach 1 and Approach 2. Or is it better to open a realm instance in `onCreate()` method of an Activity using `relam = Realm.getDefaultInstance()` and close it in `onDestroy()` using `realm.close()`.

Comment: That's no singleton, you're leaking Realm instance in every method

Comment: @EpicPandaForce How can i then handle the situation without leaking instance. I have gone through your articles on realm. But still it would be helpful if you can suggest here.

Comment: Also i want to know why will it leak even if we close using RealmManager.closeRealm() method.

Comment: `Realm.getDefaultInstance();` increases a ref count, but `close()` decrements it only once

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Okay now i understood. Thank you for your precious time. Now i have updated my question with approach 2. Could you please spare a minute on it? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realm is hard to use under a "singleton manager" because `Realm.getDefaultInstance()` might seem like you're getting something that's a "singleton", but it's really not. Instances of Realm are `thread-local` and `reference-counted`, each call to `getInstance()` increments a ref count while `close()` decrements it.

I've said a few times that `open()` would have been a better name, but I came to this conclusion far too late :)

First, the reason why your Singleton approach is not good is because:

- Calls to the methods can only be done from the thread that first calls `RealmManager.getInstance()`, which is expected to the UI thread (but not guaranteed)
- You hard-code that you want to execute each 1 operation in 1 async transaction, so you can't use this thing on a background thread too much

In order to make a realm manager that can be invoked on any threads, and UI thread uses async transaction while background thread uses sync transaction, you'd need to use a [method like **this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47845278/2413303).

And also, you'd need to track the open Realm instance for that given thread, so that you can access it wherever you want, without incrementing the ref count.

```
public class RealmManager {
    private final ThreadLocal<Realm> localRealm = new ThreadLocal<>();

    public Realm openLocalInstance() {
        Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        if(localRealm.get() == null) {
            localRealm.set(realm);
        }
        return realm;
    }

    public Realm getLocalInstance() {
        Realm realm = localRealm.get();
        if(realm == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("No open Realms were found on this thread.");
        }
        return realm;
    }

    public void closeLocalInstance() {
        Realm realm = localRealm.get();
        if(realm == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                "Cannot close a Realm that is not open.");
        }
        realm.close();
        if(Realm.getLocalInstanceCount(Realm.getDefaultConfiguration()) <= 0) {
            localRealm.set(null);
        }
    }
```

With a class like this, you could do:

```
try {
    realmManager.openLocalInstance();
    // Realm is open and can be accessed on this thread with `realmManager.getLocalInstance()`
    // also all your methods in the RealmManager can use `getLocalInstance()`
} finally {
    realmManager.closeLocalInstance();
}
```

---

---

I also created a library a while ago that [wraps Realm in such a way that it eliminates the need for manual reference counting](https://github.com/Zhuinden/realm-monarchy/), but it never really caught on. Check out the source if curious.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helped :)

Comment: Also i am curious to know the disadvantage of Approach 2. Any comments on it?